# Java program does not continue after exception

Tags: java

```
    public void dropChecker (int column, String colour) throws GameException {
            
        } else {
            // Drop the piece as far as it will go. Find the first empty space, starting from the bottom
            for (int y = HEIGHT - 1; y >= 0; y--){
                String val = getElement(y, column);
                if ((val).equals("empty")) {
                    setElement(y, column, colour);
                } else {
                    throw new GameException("Column is full");
                }
            
                
                
                
            }               
            
        }
    }
```

I have created an exception to say the column is full, while the program throws this exception, it just stops at that point, what is wrong with this

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Program execution continues where the exception is caught. If it isn't caught, your program terminates. Can you please [edit] your question and make it a [mcve] to clarify what you are asking? See also [ask].

Comment: Note that `if (isGameActive = false)` is equivalent to `if (false)`. You should instead be using: `if (!isGameActive)`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to put in a `catch` block to handle the exception and then move the program along

Answer (score 0):

When a Java program throw a Exception, by an unexpected error, or by a business flow of yours, the exception is raised to the method who called it.

It goes up until it reaches one of the following two scenarios:

1. If the Exception reaches a `catch` block, the Exception is stopped and handle by the application code: Doing some log, warning the users, or even, ignoring it.
2. **Your scenario:** if no catch block is reached, the application will exit with a status code of error! Think about the exception reaching your main method and finding nothing more! **That is your problem!**

If you want that your application keeps going, you must provide a **catch** block in some part of your code to handle that error!.

See https://howtodoinjava.com/java/exception-handling/try-catch-finally/

Answer (score 0):

You have set the exception in `dropChecker` function, but haven't handled the exception.

So what you need to do is to handle it with `Try Catch` where you called the `dropChecker` function.

Example :

```
try {
  dropChecker(0, "Green");
}
catch(GameException gameException) {
  Toast.makeText(this, gameException.message.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```